# How can I make a id to be String in Java Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got the following piece of code:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final String id = null; // there's Long data type originally

    @Version
    private Long version;

}
```

If I run it, I get:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String
```

If I remove a `@GeneratedValue` annotation I still get:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()
```

The problem is that my object may contain string values under `id` field so I want to change `Long` to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

I should have use the following 2 lines:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
```

instead of

```
@GeneratedValue
```